# Correlation between two xts R Quantmod BCBA stocks

Tags: r, correlation

At first, excuse me for my english level.

I'm trying to make a correlation beetween 2 xts objects. 
The objects are 2 argentinian stocks - BCBA:FRAN and BCBA:GGAL (tickers according to google finance).

I tried with quantmod

```
getSymbols("BCBA:FRAN", src="google") 
getSymbols("BCBA:GGAL", src="google") 

correlacion <- cbind(diff(log(Cl("BCBA:GGAL"))),diff(log(Cl("BCBA:FRAN"))))
```

But that code results in:

> Error in Cl("BCBA:GGAL") : 
>     subscript out of bounds: no column name containing "Close"

I think that i should rename the columnnames , but i don't know how could i make a correlation between 2 xts files

I hope you could help me.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't need to quote the names of the object. Look at the `auto.assign` option in `getSymbols`. To get the correlation try:

```
     cor(na.omit(merge(ROC(Cl(BCBA:FRAN)), ROC(Cl(BCBA:GGAL))))
```

Note the `na.omit` because `cor` doesn't like NAs and ROC will introduce at least one NA.